# How to allow backgroundworker to update UI and set (metro) progressring for it?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I'm working with c# only a half year ago,I'm learning.
I have a program which is helping me at my work,It communicates with 4 kind of databases at my workplace. It's working perfectly,but now i want to design to make It much cooler,but I stuck when i wanted to setup a progress ring,because my methods freeze UI while they are communicating with my databases.
I want to setup a background worker,i tried everything what i found even invoke too but nothing made it work.

```
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    BackgroundWorker workerThread = null;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InstantiateWorkerThread();

        progressrinG.IsActive = true;
    }
    private void InstantiateWorkerThread()
    {
        workerThread = new BackgroundWorker();
        workerThread.ProgressChanged += WorkerThread_ProgressChanged;
        workerThread.DoWork += WorkerThread_DoWork;
        workerThread.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkerThread_RunWorkerCompleted;
        workerThread.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        //workerThread.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    }

    private void WorkerThread_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void WorkerThread_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void WorkerThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //My huge method,asking 4 database that would update UI too
        //... Textboxes,Grids,Expanders.
    }

    private void Button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        workerThread.RunWorkerAsync();

        while (workerThread.IsBusy)
        {
            progressrinG.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

Even with Invoke,when I press the button,after 5-10 seconds It finishes my method,but my App is frozen while doing it and i dont see the progressring.

Any ideas about what do i do wrong? Or what should i do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't update the UI from a worker thread in `WorkerThread_DoWork`, instead do so via the UI thread in `WorkerThread_ProgressChanged`.

Periodically call `worker.ReportProgress` from your worker passing an arbitary percent progress so that `WorkerThread_ProgressChanged` is called.  Update the UI only when the percent difference has changed to prevent UI update exhaustion.

Comment: I try to find a sample now how to do it,and then I'll try to edit my method. Thank you. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if you've already found an example but I've recently done this myself. It's slightly different but can be adapted to what you need. I have a spinner that I kick off from a button click that also executes my methods, I then have a label that I update using ReportProgress like MickyD suggested.

```
        private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progress = e.ProgressPercentage;
        progressLabel.Text = "Creating User " + totalUserCreatedCount + " of " + rowCount;
    }
```

I go through a loop that I report on every time I start at the top of the loop again. I call ProgressChanged like this

```
backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((100 * i) / rowCount);
```

Row count is the total number of times that I want to go round the loop.

Hope this makes sense?